# Background-image css fails to display in IE7 & 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

For some reason I'm having issues displaying a background image in IE 7 and IE8. In IE9 and more modern browsers it works and outputs the following:

[image: Correct Image]

(The CSS produces the grey bordered elements around the Login)

However in IE7 and IE8 all I get is the following:

[image: IE8 and 7 display]

I cannot remember having this issue with other sites that I made cross-compatible but then again I try and avoid using images nowadays to save on page load times.

My CSS is as follows:

```
#contentright .panel {
   background-image: url("/incl/images/bg_panel200.gif");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


#contentright .panelbottom {
background-image: url("/incl/images/bg_panelbottom200.gif");
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I did a quick Google search and some previous Stack Overflow answers have suggested amending the CSS to the the following format:

```
 background: url('/incl/images/bg_panelbottom200.gif') no-repeat center top;
```

However this doesn't appear to work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use CSS defined rounded borders?

Comment: Because they aren't supported in IE8 and IE7.

Comment: Best practice is to round the corners on border using CSS and let the borders degrade gracefully to older browsers.  Using a background image like that is an awkward solution.

Comment: I know. Hence why I wouldn't do it like that but I'm afraid this code has come from a client and they want it implemented in the same way across all browsers. Unfortunately they don't believe in graceful degradation (which is what I do on all my other projects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is my first responsive design, I have had to use media queries to adapt the css based upon the screen/viewport size. It appears that only the "media="'screen'" and "media='print'" declarations work in IE7 and IE8 meaning my declaration of :  will not work. This is the reason my background-images are not displaying because IE7 and 8 do not understand this declaration and therefore ignore it. Thanks for the other valid answers guys but they are things I already knew about and had tried.

Comment: Ya I noticed this because I saw your list items and the other borders you had. I thought you have broken some css. Because not only backgrounds but also most of css has not work.

Comment: Exactly although I wasn't sure of that because they also provided me with an IE specific stylesheet which I haven't even looked at yet so I assumed that was causing the formatting issues elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `height` of the div background for it to show in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `display:block` for the elements and set the `width` and the `height` also use `border:none; background-color:transparent`

Comment: background-color:transparent helps, IE 7 and 8 can not handle expressions like rgba(0,0,0,0) for example, only rgb(0,0,0) or transparent.