# IE CSS Issue with Background Image URL

Tags: css

I am trying to use an arrow image to show for when a user expands and collapses a section.  The arrow image shows in Firefox, but in IE(8 and 11) it doesn't even appear.  Does anyone know what the issue could be?  I have an IE stylesheet I can add IE code to.  Thanks.

```
#toggleid_CrisisContact.title.isToggleTitle.isToggleCollapsed {
background:  url("/cs/ps/cache/NCC_TOGGLE_CLOSED_PNG_1.png") no-repeat scroll 2px center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#toggleid_CrisisContact.title.isToggleTitle.isToggleExpanded {
background:  url("/cs/ps/cache/NCC_TOGGLE_OPEN_PNG_1.png") no-repeat scroll 2px center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: try using `background-image: url('..')` and setting the position etc separately for your IE sheet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295928/background-image-css-fails-to-display-in-ie7-8 Try taking a look at this link

Comment: I tried background-image, but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Did you give height?

Comment: i did not list a height for it...